# Regex add in the middle

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

In JavaScript assume I have a string: **"test test hello test test"**

I know how to replace the 'hello' with 'byebye':

```
replace("hello","byebye");
```

But what is the best way to add 'byebye' right after 'hello', so my string will become: **"test test hello byebye test test"**, using regex?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way, would be to use a capturing group. Like this:

```
replace(/(hello)/, "$1 byebye");
```

[Docs on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/amaan/xBvj9/)

Comment: So the $1 is referring to the expression?

Comment: @Igor That is correct. Every group of parentheses creates a new capturing group. In this case there's only one, which is referred to by `$1`. You could have more, depending on what you need.

Comment: One more thing... What would be an example for 2 expressions? How do I separate them in the replace()?

Comment: But see also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Deprecated_and_obsolete_features?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FDeprecated_Features#RegExp_Properties

Comment: An example: `"test test hello test test".replace(/(test)\ (hello)/, "This is test: $1. This is hello: $2");`

Comment: @KooiInc Oh, thanks for that! What would some recommended replacements be? Using `exec` or something?

Comment: @KooiInc So if I'm not to use it.. What would you suggest instead?

Comment: I think I may have misinterpreted this: it's about *RegExp properties*, so `RegExp.$1`. Furthermore MDN does provide examples using `$1 $2 ...` within `String.replace`. I wouldn't be too worried then. Also check: http://www.merlyn.demon.co.uk/js-valid.htm

Comment: @KooiInc Ooh, wow. I didn't even know the RegExp object had those properties. Probably why I never knew they were deprecated either. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to explore alternatives anyway, using a replacement function would be an idea: see a fork of your jsfiddle @ http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/AkWMG/

Comment: @KooiInc Thanks.. But how to implement the multiple regex expressions in one replace()? If its possible..

Comment: @Igor: adjust the replacement function, see the edited jsfiddle @ http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/AkWMG/

Answer (score 2):

Would this work?

```
replace("hello","hello byebye");
```

As for replacement while preserving original content, a RegEx can certainly fetch the correct position, but I think Replace() is what is limiting you.

Comment: Yes, But what if my value to replace is a regex expression?